# Можно ли оставить предложение с таким количеством тире?

Tags: тире

Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и т. п. – но – увы – нет России.

Варианты:

Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и т. п., но, увы, нет России.

Среди участников форума Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и т. п., но – увы – нет России.

Как лучше решить?

Answer (score 1):

Мне наиболее естественным видится имеющийся вариант с запятыми и самым первым тире (оно замещает пропущенный глагол "есть/представлены"). Если нужно сделать акцент на "увы", можно вместо запятых применить скобки и добавить восклицательный знак: (увы!).

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

> Среди участников форума – Бразилия,
> Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и
> Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная
> Африка, арабские страны Залива и т. п.

Мне не нравится "и т. п." в этом предложении.

Я бы сделал так:

*Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива... Но – увы! – нет России.*

Или так:

*Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива... Но, увы, нет России.*

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант. Оригинальный. А можно ли сделать так: Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и т.п. – но, увы – нет России. Или тире перед "но" лишнее?

Comment: Нет. Просто хороший. Без "тоже".

Потому что в других представленных выше вариантах есть "и т. п.", из-за чего их нельзя ТОЖЕ считать хорошими. Попробуйте полностью (без сокращений) написать это "и т. п.":

"Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и тому подобные". (???) Нравится? 

Правильным было бы в этом предложении использовать вместо "и т. п." другое сокращение: "и др". 



А лучше -- воспользоваться многоточием. Как у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Если в своём вопросе Вы имели в виду соответствие **- или несоответствие!-** правилам орфографии, (а этот термин **- может не знаете? -** означает правописание!), то такое предложение **- в соответствии с общепринятыми современными нормами! -** ничем не будет её нарушать, если Вы **- конечно же! -** не подразумевали неписанные каноны грамматики **- что, в свою очередь, подразумевает грамотность построения речи! -** согласно которым такое предложение имеет кое-какие изъяны, на часть которых **- как видите и сами! -** уже обращены внимания **- чуть выше! -** и внимания эти **- заметьте это! -** вполне обоснованы, равно, как и  **- надеюсь не будете спорить с этим?! -** замечания. :)

Не без шутка юмора, разумеется. Но... 
Предложение у меня, если хоть как-то можно назвать выдержанным с точки зрения орфографии, однако грамматика построения речи желает лучшего. 
Также хочу подчеркнуть, что мои "тире" **- почти в каждом случае! -** могут быть заменены на запятые, и также можно убрать везде восклицательные знаки ("!"). И всё это можно соотнести и к Вашему случаю, уважаемый пользователь псевдонима "Alenka"... ИМХО, конечно же.

Comment: Я, разумеется, имела в виду соответствие этого предложения нормам грамматики. А вот можно ли обращать "внимания" в каком бы то ни было контексте - это еще вопрос...

Comment: Когда мы говорим: "У NN грамотно построенная речь!" мы же не имеем в виду орфографию, которую мы не можем определить в устной речи. Да и сама грамматика, являясь разделом лингвистики, включает в себя изучение грамотного составления речи. Уместность - неуместность! - ставить всякие знаки препинания относится к правописанию или, как иначе его называют, к орфографии. Это тоже раздел языкознания, но он уже изучает правильность не составления предложений, а написания слов.
Поэтому Ваше предложение хворает с точки зрения грамматики языка и не имеет ошибки с точки зрения орфографии. ИМХО.

Comment: Иначе говоря сам Ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к "нормам грамматики", это из области орфографии. В своём ответе я, конечно же, затронул вопрос о грамматике, но это было сделано исключительно ради составления примера предложения, где было бы безумное изобилие тире. Мой окончательный ответ на суть вопроса:
**Вы безусловно можете составить и "оставить предложение" и не только с четырьмя тире, а даже с двадцать раз большим его количеством!**

Comment: Что же касается выбора **из предложенных вариантов**, то я бы предпочёл этот:

**Среди участников форума – Бразилия, Великобритания, Канада, Европейский и Южноамериканский комитеты, Южная Африка, арабские страны Залива и т. п., но, увы, нет России.**